# Is that possible to define dynamic value of tag "var" in richfaces datatable?

Tags: jsf, richfaces

Is that possible to define dynamic value of tag "var" in richfaces datatable?

I have a component that contains rich datatable inside and I want to use custom "var" name.

I do so

Component:

```
<rich:extendedDataTable id="#{id}_list" cellspacing="0" rows="#{rows}" var="#{itemName}"
                            value="#{data}">
```

Page:

```
<wh:list id="f" data="#{deviceListBean.data}" rows="20" itemName="item">
```

But I get such exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: var cannot be EL-expression
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606)
```

I want to be able use custom "var" name. May be there is some another way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a trick (`name` attribute of `ui:param` can be EL-expression):

```
<ui:param name="#{itemName}" value="#{item}"/>
<rich:extendedDataTable var="item" value="#{data}">
```

Comment: Nice one. Noted should be that this trick works in Mojarra only.

Comment: Could you please post an example for that?

Answer (score 0):

`var` is the name that you use to reference each item that is being looped in the datatable.

You would do something like

```
<rich:extendedDataTable id="#{id}_list" cellspacing="0" rows="#{rows}" var="_dataItem"
                        value="#{data}">
```

And inside the data table,  you can use `_dataItem` to referent the current value

```
<rich:column>
  <h:outputLabel value="#{_itemData.myValue}"/>
</rich:column>
```

Think of it as if defining the following `for`

```
for(Item _dataItem : data) {
   System.out.println(_dataItem.myValue);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know that. The problem is that I do not want to use the **same** name (_itemData) for current value in all tables. I want to user **different** names. F.e. **_deviceItem** for device list and **_userItem** for user list.

Comment: If you have different datatables you can use a different name for each one. If you are somewhat reusing one (I do not advice it) you cannot.

Comment: How to define different names if I cannot use EL-expression and the table is "hidden" **within a component**? How to pass that name to the datatable?

Comment: Ok, missed the component part. But why do you wnat that? Are you using that name outside of the component?

Comment: I have a list component with different additional functionality and want to use it on many of my pages. But I dont like to use same var name on all pages. Especially taking to account that I may have **nested lists**.

Comment: But the idea of the component is just to hide that complexity from you, so you don't have to worry about how the component works internally. The inner component won't be confused by the outer component var name (specially given that that a composite component is a `NamingComponent`). You are trying to do something that can not be done and that will solve a problem that does not exist.